# Using PBOs when memory address is already fixed?

Tags: opengl, texture2d, pbo

I'm trying to optimize the upload of textures from CPU memory to OpenGL.

Initially I was using `glTexImage2D` and that works, but obviously isn't using DMA, so I'm trying to use PBOs.

Unfortunately, the API I have to use that provides the texture data allocates the CPU memory for them and returns a pointer. I can't control where in memory it places the data.

If I create a PBO then map it, I have to either 'manually' move my data into the PBO-allocated memory, or use `glBufferData` to initialize it with the texture data before calling `glTexImage2D`. This appears significantly slower than not using a PBO at all.

Any other techniques I could try, or is this just a limitation of how PBO's work?

Comment: What about [`glTexSubImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 - Can you elaborate - I'm not sure how that's going to help, as I still need to move the entire texture?

Comment: Of course you have to move the entire texture from the CPU to the GPU. But while [`glTexImage2D `](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) creates new texture object and a new data store, `glTexSubImage2D` just writes to an existing data store.

Comment: Thanks! Understood. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Done, but `glTexSubImage2D` isn't making any measurable difference. I think the size of the pixel transfers I'm making (8 megapixels per call) swamps any per-call overhead improvement.